# Can I minimize application windows to a taskbar in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome-shell, panel, taskbar, window-management

Is there a way to drop windows down into a taskbar in GNOME, then later restore them by clicking on the entry in the bar?

The Windows operating system, as well as some desktop environments in Ubuntu, but not GNOME 3, have a panel called the [taskbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar) which contains a window list. Application windows can be minimized (iconified) and shown only in that list, then restored by clicking on them in the list.

Is this possible with GNOME Shell in Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 3):

There are some [GNOME shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) which may help you achieve this goal.

1. [Window List](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/)
   It displays a list of open windows at the bottom of the screen. You'll be able to minimise and restore windows by clicking on the window names.
2. [Window List Mod](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1033/window-list-mod/)
   It's a modification of the *Window List* extension. It displays a list of open windows at the top of the screen and offers a few more customisations.

Comment: Now, is not possible install gnome extension in U 17.10. So I am going to wait for final release.

Comment: @dDo I see. Did you try manual installation? First download extension (zip archive) for the right GNOME version from extensions.gnome.org and then extract and copy the extension folder (e.g. `window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github`) to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Finally activate it using GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: I did it this way, but after it there is not new extension in extension tab in Gnome Tweak

Answer (score 0):

Try installing tint2. It maintains (amongst other functions) a list of minimised windows in a window list.