# Show open windows on top panel

Tags: gnome-shell, panel

Is there a way to show all OPEN apps/windows on the top panel in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME DE?

Similar to how it displays ACTIVE windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) called "[Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)". It's

> An icon taskbar for the Gnome Shell. This extension moves the dash into the gnome main panel so that the application launchers and system tray are combined into a single panel, similar to that found in KDE Plasma and Windows 7+. A separate dock is no longer needed for easy access to running and favorited applications.

You can also set the position of the panel to top or bottom from the extension's preferences window as shown in this screenshot:
[image]
(screenshot source: [this Web Upd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/01/dash-to-panel-is-cool-icon-taskbar-for.html))

Comment: that sounds like a great idea, except I like having a separate panel for my favorited apps. The top panel that shows open apps, then becomes less cluttered. I can do this on xfce and KDE. But I may just have to resort to your suggestion for gnome. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you may also want to consider having a separate new taskbar with open windows at the bottom (refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/961581/480481)). I am not aware of any (relatively simple) solution that puts running application windows at the existing top bar.

Comment: Actually, I tried dash to panel and it allowed me to do exactly what I wanted to do! It lets me disable favorited apps from it, and it allows me to keep my dash to dock panel on the bottom. Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/HyU9jca  my bottom panel has intelihide enabled so it hides when windows try to occupy it's space.